# What is a convex support? (Bickel&Doksum, Mathematical Statistics, Basic ideas...Vol1)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, terminology, exponential-family

Bickel&Doksum, Mathematical Statistics, Basic ideas...Vol1

page 122, just above Cor2.3.1, it says:

> Define the *convex support* of a probability P to be the smallest convex set C such that P(C)=1.

I don't think this definition is quite common since I had hard time searching it without any reasonable result.

To prove the existence of MLE in canonical exponential family or Cor2.3.1, I need to understand this one in a rigorous way.

Any ideas or comments would be helpful.

Comment: I think it is just the support set [1] which is also convex. [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28measure_theory%29

Comment: @TenaliRaman Thanks, but I'm still confused with it because we don't usually postulate addition or constant multiplication on elements of $\Sigma$.

Comment: In other words, how do I think of convex combination of elements in a support of $\mu$?

Comment: if you check the definition, the support is defined in terms of elements of X instead of elements of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I mistakenly see the motivation part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such definition is often used in the context of distribution families like poison or binomial supported on integers. Take as an example the binomial family $\text{Binom}(n,p), \quad 0<p<1$ where the support is the finite set $\{0,1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ and the convex support is its convex closure, $[0,n]$. I'm not really sure what you do not understand, the definition you have given seems clear. The support of the distribution (family) is the smallest set that have probability 1 (sometimes defined as the smallest closed set that ...) and the convex support is the convex closure of the support, which is the set of all convex combinations of points in the support.

Another example, for the poisson the support is $\{0,1,2,\dotsc \}$ and the convex support is $[0,\infty)$.  To see this definitions in action the book by L D Brown: "Fundamentals of Statistical Exponential Families: With Applications in Statistical Decision Theory" is a good source.